# Stop Apache Camel from logging full path of file being moved

Tags: java, apache-camel, camel-ftp

I'm using Apache Camel for moving a file from one place to another. While moving, it logs the full file path. Is there a way to hide it?

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
from(source).routeId(ROUTE_ID)
            .marshal()
            .process(processor)
            .setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, constant("file.txt"))
            .to(destination)
            .end();
```

And here's the log (please check at the end of the log):

```
2020-04-04 03:42:49,013 INFO task-1 org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext doStartOrResumeRouteConsumers - Route: MyRoute started and consuming from: file:///Users/user/Desktop/?include=file.csv
```

Also I have another small question:
Is there a difference between using `?fileName="desiredFileName.txt"` option in the filePath & using `setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, constant("desiredFileName.txt"))` ? I doubt that adding fileName parameter is renaming file on the server, and not doing it locally, and then uploading it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot disable that log line without changing logging level or by creating your own version of camel core. That logging is defined on [this line.](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/0f8ad1a3a42f1f50e863a8b2ff092cd6df3df43b/core/camel-base/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/impl/engine/AbstractCamelContext.java#L3404) in AbstractCamelContext. But good thing is that it happens only once when the route ist started.

There is no difference in using fileName in option or the Exchange.FILE_NAME header. But if fileName option is set, it will be used over the FILE_NAME header.

Comment: In latest Camel versions then the logging is reduced so parameters of the endpoints are not logged. I have created a ticket to add an option so you can turn off the logging of the endpoints: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-14844